# I upgraded to 12.04 but my PC boots to command line instead of Unity or Gnome2. Help!

Tags: 12.04

I upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 but my PC boots to command line instead of Unity or Gnome2. I can follow directions and usually find my own answers, but I'm not having any luck so far. Help!?

Comment: What happens when typing startx ?

Comment: I'm working through the same thing.  So far I've figured out that my Logitech USB headset causes a segfault when running startx.  I pulled it out and rebooted.  I got into the GUI, but then compiz puked for as yet unknown reasons.  It's doing its Apport thing now.  If I get farther on the next reboot I'll post another update.

Comment: When I type startx then hit enter, I get a small window that says 'Failed to load session "ubuntu" ' with a 'log out' button (which I can't click on so I hit enter)

I then get a whole bunch of things from the application loading and then failing with a message: 'Failed to load module "fglrx" (module does not exist, 0)'

I would be happy just for instructions back to 11.10 without having to wipe everything out...

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for a slow response, but you may want to try `sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh` to remove `flgrx` which appears to be acting improperly.

Also try 
`sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*` and if you get a warning, run:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/lib/fglrx
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/lib32/fglrx
```

followed by the command to purge the package(listed above). I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have the proprietary video drivers installed?

I used to often have failures such as that, and finally found out that it was a simple fix to get going...

I used a live CD to get access to the non-booting distro, and edited the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.  The wrong information in this file can cause catastrophic failures for X-windows.  I think it is no longer used in 12.04, but if present, I believe it will be used.  So, the first thing to try might be to rename it to something like "xorg.cong.11.10" to disable it, and see if it boots.